# Conditional Formatting applied to an Excel sheet using Java, is not applied to the cell even after refreshing them

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

I have been trying to do conditional formatting for a specific range of Excel cells using Java, Apache poi. For cells having TRUE or FALSE values the background should be set to a particular color based on the given rules. 
Same code worked for numbers when valuebasedformatting was applied while writing the file. 
Until I refresh each cell by selecting them and double clicking , the changes are not applied. Is there any way to refresh the entire sheet using Java?

Have tried using evaluateAllFormulaCells() function as `XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);`

But that also failed to make any changes. The conditional formatting method is as follows :

```
SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

              ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(CFRuleRecord.ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "FALSE");
              PatternFormatting fill1 = rule1.createPatternFormatting();
              fill1.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
              fill1.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);


              ConditionalFormattingRule rule2 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(CFRuleRecord.ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "TRUE");
              PatternFormatting fill2 = rule2.createPatternFormatting();
              fill2.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.index);
              fill2.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

           CellRangeAddress[] regions = {
                   CellRangeAddress.valueOf("AP1:BH47")
           };

           sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1, rule2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your "TRUE" and "FALSE" cell values in `Excel` are not really the Boolean cell values `TRUE` and `FALSE` but string cell values. But your rules only check for Boolean cell values.

The first part of  the following code (conditional formatting rules in `A1:A4`) shows the problem. The second part (conditional formatting rules in `C1:C4`) shows how a formula conditional formatting rule could be used to check both, Boolean `TRUE` / `FALSE` as well as the strings "TRUE" / "FALSE".

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class ConditionalFormattingBooleanValues {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(true); //boolean value TRUE in A1
  sheet.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue(true); //boolean value TRUE in C1
  sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue(false); //boolean value FALSE in A2
  sheet.getRow(1).createCell(2).setCellValue(false); //boolean value FALSE in C2
  sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellValue("TRUE"); //text value "TRUE" in A3
  sheet.getRow(2).createCell(2).setCellValue("TRUE"); //text value "TRUE" in C3
  sheet.createRow(3).createCell(0).setCellValue("FALSE"); //text value "FALSE" in A4
  sheet.getRow(3).createCell(2).setCellValue("FALSE"); //text value "FALSE" in C4

  SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

  ConditionalFormattingRule rule1;
  ConditionalFormattingRule rule2;
  PatternFormatting fill;
  ConditionalFormattingRule[] cfRules;
  CellRangeAddress[] regions;

  // check only boolean values in rules in A1:A4
  rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "FALSE");
  fill = rule1.createPatternFormatting();
  fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  rule2 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(ComparisonOperator.EQUAL, "TRUE");
  fill = rule2.createPatternFormatting();
  fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.index);
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule1, rule2};
  regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:A4")};
  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  // check boolean and text values in rules in C1:C4
  String formula1 = 
   (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook)?"OR(INDIRECT(\"C\"&ROW())=FALSE,INDIRECT(\"C\"&ROW())=\"FALSE\")":"OR(C1=FALSE,C1=\"FALSE\")";
  rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(formula1);
  fill = rule1.createPatternFormatting();
  fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index);
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  String formula2 = 
   (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook)?"OR(INDIRECT(\"C\"&ROW())=TRUE,INDIRECT(\"C\"&ROW())=\"TRUE\")":"OR(C1=TRUE,C1=\"TRUE\")";
  rule2 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(formula2);
  fill = rule2.createPatternFormatting();
  fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.index);
  fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  cfRules = new ConditionalFormattingRule[]{rule1, rule2};
  regions = new CellRangeAddress[]{CellRangeAddress.valueOf("C1:C4")};
  sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, cfRules);

  String fileout = (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook)?"ConditionalFormattingBooleanValues.xls":"ConditionalFormattingBooleanValues.xlsx";
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileout);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Axel .I tried to implement the code you have provided, but this also makes no effect. I have tried using it as for text values, since my value is not boolean. Only if my cells are refreshed, the conditional formatting is visible.

Comment: @Sonia Mathew: My code is complete, tested and works for me. So, sorry, I cannot reproduce your issue.